# Crontab for Virtual Hosts

Tags: linux, apache, cron, virtualhost

I've got several Virtual Hosts set up on my Apache (Linux) server. I'd like each Virtual Host to have its own set of cronjobs so that they can be managed independently without the risk of one Virtual Host conflicting with another. Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way for me is to create local users on the machine where those virtual hosts reside and give each user rights to manage particular virtual host (config, cron, etc)